# Pytest marks: mark entire directory / package

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am testing several versions of a component using Pytest. Some tests can run on all versions, some are version specific. For example

```
tests
|
|-- version1_tests
|   |-- test_feature_1_1.py
|   |-- test_feature_1_2.py
|   |-- test_feature_1_n.py
| 
|-- version2_tests
|   |-- test_feature_2_1.py
|   |-- test_feature_2_2.py
|   |-- test_feature_2_n.py
|
|-- common_tests
|   |-- test_feature_common_1.py
|   |-- test_feature_common_2.py
|   |-- test_feature_common_n.py
```

I would like to mark my tests such that I can select if I want to test Version 1 (version1_tests + common_tests) or Version 2 (version2_tests + common_tests) from the command line.

The way I am currently doing this is for each test module, I add a pytest marker and then specify the marker from the command line. For example, in `test_feature_1_1.py`:

```
import pytest
pytestmark = pytest.mark.version1

class TestSpecificFeature(object):
    ...
```

And then to run: `python -m pytest -m "common and version1"`

This works fine, but I have to manually add the marker to every module, which is tedious because there are actually dozens (not 3 like in the example).

We used to use Robot Framework, where it was trivial to "mark" an entire folder by adding tags into the `__init__.robot` files. Is there any equivalent way to do this in Pytest, or is marking each module the best I can do?

Comment: Wouldn't `pytest -k "common and version1"` work? Aside from that, you can of course assign markers dynamically via `item.add_marker()` based on whatever condition you need.

Comment: Although that does not use markers as I had originally asked, for my situation, it works perfectly and I think it is an even better solution than what I was looking for. Would you mind posting it as an answer, and maybe also elaborating a bit on the use of `item.add_marker()` or any other solution that might actually use markers? Just so that if someone reads this later and the solution using expressions does not work for them they can have another option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can register markers to collected tests at runtime using `item.add_marker()` method. Here's an example of registering markers in [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems):

```
import pathlib
import pytest


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    # python 3.4/3.5 compat: rootdir = pathlib.Path(str(config.rootdir))
    rootdir = pathlib.Path(config.rootdir)
    for item in items:
        rel_path = pathlib.Path(item.fspath).relative_to(rootdir)
        mark_name = next((part for part in rel_path.parts if part.endswith('_tests')), '').removesuffix('_tests')
        if mark_name:
            mark = getattr(pytest.mark, mark_name)
            item.add_marker(mark)
```

Write the code to `conftest.py` in the project root dir and try it out:

```
$ pytest -m "common or version2" --collect-only -q
tests/common_tests/test_feature_common_1.py::test_spam
tests/common_tests/test_feature_common_1.py::test_eggs
tests/common_tests/test_feature_common_2.py::test_spam
tests/common_tests/test_feature_common_2.py::test_eggs
tests/common_tests/test_feature_common_n.py::test_spam
tests/common_tests/test_feature_common_n.py::test_eggs
tests/version2_tests/test_feature_2_1.py::test_spam
tests/version2_tests/test_feature_2_1.py::test_eggs
tests/version2_tests/test_feature_2_2.py::test_spam
tests/version2_tests/test_feature_2_2.py::test_eggs
tests/version2_tests/test_feature_2_n.py::test_spam
tests/version2_tests/test_feature_2_n.py::test_eggs
```

Only tests under `common_tests` and `version2_tests` were selected.

#### Explanation

For each collected test item, we extract the path relative to project root dir (`rel_path`), first part of `rel_path` that ends with `_tests` will be used as source for the mark name extraction. E.g. `collect_tests` is the source for the mark name `collect` etc. Once we have the mark name, we create the mark (using `getattr` since we can't use the property access) and append the mark via `item.add_marker(mark)`. You can write your own, less abstract version of it, e.g.

```
for item in items:
    if `common_tests` in str(item.fspath):
        item.add_marker(pytest.mark.common)
    elif `version1_tests` in str(item.fspath):
        item.add_marker(pytest.mark.version1)
    elif `version2_tests` in str(item.fspath):
        item.add_marker(pytest.mark.version2)
```

#### Registering markers

With a recent version of `pytest`, you should receive a `PytestUnknownMarkWarning` since the dynamically generated markers were not registered. Check out the section [Registering markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#registering-markers) for a solution - you can either add the mark names in `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
markers =
    common
    version1
    version2
```

or add them dynamically via [`pytest_configure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) hook, e.g.

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    rootdir = pathlib.Path(config.rootdir)
    for dir_ in rootdir.rglob('*_tests'):
        mark_name = dir_.stem.removesuffix('_tests')
        config.addinivalue_line('markers', mark_name)
```

Comment: `rstrip` isn't used correctly here. If the dirname is `e2e_tests` and you do `rstrip('_tests')` you'll get `e2` as a result because it is searching for any of the chars in `_tests` to remove, until it hits the `2` which isn't in the list.

```'e2e_tests'.rstrip('_tests') == 'e2'```

try:

```mark_name = dir_.stem[:-len('_tests')]```

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly the same thing by putting `__init__.py` file in each directory with the version tag:

```
pytestmark = pytest.mark.version1
```

and import it inside test

```
from . import pytestmark
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a different approach here.
It is better to have only one way to run your tests.

You must give your tests the ability to distinguish which version is currently being tested.

And by that you could have only one `common tests` folder.

If test can not be run on specific version use `skipif`.
If test will fail on specific version use `xfail`.

Please refer to [the skipping docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish that would be during the pytest call.

You can't really mark a directory as you want, because you are only able to mark modules and functions.

*So instead you can do the following.*

**Run all tests in a directory: [package]**
This will accomplish what you want.

```
# pytest <dir_name>[/<sub_dir_name>]
pytest tests/version1_tests
```

There are other ways to invoke pytest also.

**Run all tests in a module: [file]**

```
# pytest <path_to_module>/<test_module>.py
pytest tests/version1_tests/test_feature_1_1.py
```

**Run specific test in a module: [function]**

```
# pytest <path_to_module>/<test_module>::<test_name>
pytest tests/version1_tests/test_feature_1_1::test_feature_foo
```

**Run tests by keyword expressions: [function(s)]**
The keywords that you give will be matched against the names all tests that you have, and the matching tests will be executed.

```
# this will run all tests in the version1_tests package
# since all tests there match this pattern
pytest -k "feature_1"

# run tests with "feature" in their name, but not "common"
# tests in version1_tests and version2_tests packages are executed
pytest -k "feature and not common"
```

The documentation on how to invoke pytest can be found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/usage.html).